# Terminal mysql queries

Tags: mysql, terminal

I'm looking to use terminal to execute mysql queries. I currently connect to a sql db via the sql workbench but would like to do this via terminal. Is this possible?

I've installed mysql via homebrew

when I hit mysql in terminal it says command not found, maybe I need to do something else besides the homebrew setup?

Comment: Yes, if your mysql/bin is in your `PATH` env var, you just have to type `mysql`. Type `mysql -?` to see the options.

Comment: Try with `mysql.exe`. But Check your `PATH` environment variable before by typing `set`.

Answer (score 10):

Go to the directory:

```
mysql/bin
```

To execute the query from command line:

```
mysql -u [username] -p [dbname] -e [query]
```

example:

`mysql -u root -p database -e "select * from user"`

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql --help
```

You can do also:

```
cat dump.sql | mysql -u user -p password database
```

Or:

```
echo "select * from abc;" | mysql -u user -p password database
```

Comment: What about after you are inside the mysql terminal and are already connected to a specific database? Shouldn't there be a way just to run a query from there?